# Shrink/resize an image without interpolation

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image `F` of size 1044*1408, it only has 3 integer values 0, 2, and 3.

I want to shrink it to 360*480. Now I am using `Z= cv2.resize(F,(480,380))`. But `Z` is interpolated, it has many unique values, more than just 0, 2 and 3. I can't just round up the interpolated values to the closest integer, because I will get some 1s.

`F` is read from a tif file and manipulated, it is an ndarray now. So I can't use PIL: `F = F.resize((new_width, new_height))` as `F` is not from `F = Image.open(*)`.

Comment: What you want is probably resampling the image instead of resizing it.  Since you mention `ndarray`, I assume you are using `numpy`.  Look at the solution ("numpy slicing") in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876640/subsampling-every-nth-entry-in-a-numpy-array  It will allow resampling (subsampling) without interpolation.

Comment: shouldn't CV_INTER_NN "interpolation" method choose one of the original pixel values (the one with the smallest distance to the resized pixel position)?

Comment: Yes set `interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST` will let you use the nearest pixel value. I can use `Z= cv2.resize(F,(480,380),interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)`, to get only 0,2 and 3. I am wondering is there any method that doesn't do interpolation at all

Answer (score 16):

You may use `INTER_NEAREST`:

```
Z= cv2.resize(F,(480,380),fx=0, fy=0, interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

Comment: Is there a method to upsample and increase the image size??

Comment: I don't mean super resolution.. If cv2 has that then it is great, But simple interpolation

Comment: I got interpolation anyway.

Answer (score 11):

Alternately, you can also use [`skimage.transform.resize`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.resize). Argument `order = 0` enforces nearest-neighbor interpolation.

```
   Z = skimage.transform.resize(F,
                               (480,380),
                               mode='edge',
                               anti_aliasing=False,
                               anti_aliasing_sigma=None,
                               preserve_range=True,
                               order=0)
```