# Extending steps for slicing numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

My question is similar to this: [subsampling every nth entry in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876640/subsampling-every-nth-entry-in-a-numpy-array)

Let's say I have an array as given below:
a = [1,2,2,2,3,4,1,2,2,2,3,4,1,2,2,2,3,4....]

How can I extend the slice such that I slice three elements at specific intervals? I.e. how can I slice 2s from the array?
I believe basic slicing does not work in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this through individual indexing.

We want to start from the element at index 1, take 3 elements and then skip 3 elements:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4])

start = 1
take = 3
skip = 3

indices = np.concatenate([np.arange(i, i + take) for i in range(start, len(a), take + skip)])

print(indices)
print(a[indices])
```

Output:

```
[ 1  2  3  7  8  9 13 14 15]
[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest here seems:

```
 a = np.array([1,2,2,2,3,4,1,2,2,2,3,4,1,2,2,2,3,4])
 a.reshape(-1,6)[1:4].ravel()
```

or if `a` doesn't chunk well :

```
period = 6
a.resize(np.math.ceil(a.size/period),period)
a[:,1:4].ravel()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized one with `masking` -

```
def take_sliced_regions(a, start, take, skip):
    r = np.arange(len(a))-start
    return a[r%(take+skip)<take]
```

Sample run -

```
In [90]: a = np.array([1,2,2,2,3,4,1,2,2,2,3,4,1,2,2,2,3,4,1,2])

In [91]: take_sliced_regions(a, start=1, take=3, skip=3)
Out[91]: array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```